# How to with oracle regexp_replace parse string

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a string: "ABC-30 (40D)", the result is 30, my example:

```
regexp_replace(f, '^[^-]+-(\d+)*')
```

don't work...

Comment: without regexp it works, but I'm afraid this :D substr(substr(f, - instr(reverse(f), '-') + 1), 1, instr(substr(f, - instr(reverse(f), '-') + 1), ' ')-1),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` with this pattern.

```
SELECT regexp_substr('ABC-30 (40D)', '^[^-]+-(\d+)[^0-9]+.*$' , 1 ,1 , 'i', 1  ) FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Ok, thx, pls advise, how to with regexp_like in where clause filter only digits in this example result is same: 30?

Comment: REGEXP_LIKE(f, '^[^-]+-(\d+)[^0-9]+.*$') this is work